# Python "Meeting Finder" algorithm giving wrong output

Tags: python, algorithm, calculation

Im working on an application in python that finds free days in given bounds, with given persons times in which they aren't free. It works by creating a list of possible days and then removing the days in which the perons aren't free. But depending on the boundaries given it puts our wrong "free days", when the bounds are 1 to 30 (or 31 bc the day 30 is included) it works, but when the bounds are i.e. 4 to 33 (or 34 bc the day 33 is included), wrong days are calculated. The code:

```
person_1 = ['4-16', '18-24']
person_2 = ['2-14', '17-25']
person_3 = ['6-8', '12-20']
person_4 = ['10-22']
allPeople = [person_1, person_2, person_3, person_4]

startDaySlot = 1
endDaySlot = 31
allTimeSlots = list(range(startDaySlot, endDaySlot))
commonFreeSlots = []

for i in allPeople:
    for l in i:
        startSlot, endSlot = l.split('-')
        print(startSlot + '-' + endSlot)
        del allTimeSlots[int(startSlot) - 1:int(endSlot)]
        print(str(allTimeSlots))

print(str(allTimeSlots))
```

I recommend trying the code yourself with different boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to put all available days (from 1 to 31) to set and then remove occupied days from this set for each person.

For example:

```
person_1 = ['4-16', '18-24']
person_2 = ['2-14', '17-25']
person_3 = ['6-8', '12-20']
person_4 = ['10-22']

from itertools import chain

all_days = set(range(1, 32))
for p in chain(person_1, person_2, person_3, person_4):
    start, end = map(int, p.split('-'))
    for d in range(start, end+1):
        if d in all_days:
            all_days.remove(d)

print(all_days)
```

Prints:

```
{1, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I set the day list and that fixed the problem, but I did not use itertools (just bc i am not familia rto it). Stil thanks.